# Characterization of the tangent space of an embedded submanifold via defining map

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have a confusion on function composition in the proof below by John Lee. We define $\Phi: U \to N$ to be a local defining map for $S$, i.e. $U$ is an open subset of $M$ and $S \cap U$ is a regular level set of $\Phi$. In this case, since $S$ could contain points outside of $U$, $\Phi \circ \iota$ makes sense only on $S \cap U$. But how can we split the differential of $\Phi \circ \iota $ into $d\Phi_p \circ d\iota_p$? I am not sure how this works because now we are looking at linear maps from $T_p S$ to $d\iota_p(T_p S)$ and from $T_p U$ to $T_{\Phi(p)} N$ and each space takes functions on their respective neighborhoods, i.e. a smooth function on $S \cap U$ may no longer be smooth on $U$ so the tangent vectors on each space takes smooth functions defined on different domains.

In fact, it is not clear to me how $\Phi \circ \iota$ is smooth on $S\cap U$ to begin with.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: This is the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#General_rule:_Vector-valued_functions_with_multiple_inputs)

Comment: @Didier Yes I am aware that chain rule is applied here, but I don't know why we can interchange the two inclusion maps which have different domains. I've written my concerns in the comment of Paul's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion of the embedded submanifold $\iota : S \to M$ is a smooth map.  The composition $\Psi = \Phi \circ \iota$ is defined on set $\iota^{-1}(U) = S \cap U$. Let us be more precise concerning $\Psi$. Since $S \cap U$ is open in $S$, the restriction $\iota \mid_{S \cap U}  : S \cap U \to M$ is smooth (see Proposition 2.6 (b)). Hence the map
$$\iota_U : S \cap U \to U, \iota_U(x) = \iota(x) $$
is smooth because $U$ is open in $M$.<sup>1</sup> Note that $d(\iota_U)_q = d\iota_q$ for all $q \in S \cap U$.<sup>2</sup>

So more precisely $\Psi$ stands for

$$\Psi = \Phi \circ \iota_U : U \cap S \xrightarrow{\iota_U} U \xrightarrow{\Phi} N .$$
Hence $\Psi$ is a smooth map by Proposition 2.10 (d).

Now Proposition 3.6 (b) which is a variant of the cahin rule for smooth maps between smooth manifolds applies to show
$$d\Psi_p = d\phi_{\iota_U(p)} \circ d(\iota_U)_p  = d\phi_p \circ d\iota_p .$$

---

Footnotes

1. This is a consequence of the following
   $\phantom{x}$
   **Lemma.** Let $f : M \to N$ be map between smooth manifolds such that $f(M)$ is contained in an open subset $U \subset N$. Then $f$ is smooth if and only if the "codomain restriction" of $f$ to $U$, i.e. the map $\tilde f : M \to U, \tilde f(x) = f(x)$, is smooth.
   $\phantom{x}$
   The "only if part" follows from Proposition 2.10 (c), (d). The "if part" can easily proved by using the definition of "smooth".
2. There is a slght abuse notation here when writing $d(\iota_U)_q = d\iota_q$. By Proposition 3.9 (The Tangent Space to an Open Submanifold) we can identify the tangent space to an open submanifold with the tangent space to the whole manifold. That is, we write $T_p(S \cap U) = T_pS$ and $T_pU = T_pN$ although these tangent space are not really equal, but only naturally isomorphic. But certainly
   $\require{AMScd}$
   \begin{CD}
   T_p(S \cap U) @>{\approx}>> T_pS \\
   @V{d(\iota_U)_q}VV @VV{d\iota_q}V \\
   T_pU @>>{\approx}> T_pM
    \end{CD}
   commutes since the horizontal arrows are induced by the inclusion maps $S \cap U \to S$ and $U \to M$.
   By the way, the statement $T_pS = \ker d \Phi_p$ in Proposition 5.38 only makes sense if we identify $T_pS$ with a linear subspace of $T_pM$ which is again a slight abuse of notation.

Comment: I assume you are referring to Proposition 2.10 (c), but here the inclusion map is given by $\iota: U \to M$ with $U$ being an open submanifold with or without boundary of $M$. Whereas in our case, we don't have the guarantee that $S \cap U$ is an open submanifold of $U$, which would allow 2.10 (c) to apply. And my concern with $d(\iota_U)q = d\iota_q$ for all $q \in U \cap S$, is that $d(\iota_U)q$ acts on tangent vectors in $T_q (U\cap S)$ whereas $d \iota_q$ acts on $T_q U$. So how do we know they are equal?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician See my update. You hav to familiarize yourself with the mathematical habit of writing "$=$" instead of "naturally isomorphic".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. When you say the maps commute, it is because both compositions are inclusion maps from $S\cap U$ to $M$ and we then apply chain rule to each?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Yes!

Comment: Just one minor question. When we have on the two horizontal rows two spaces isomorphic and two linear maps vertically, just as in your diagram, and they commute, do the two vertical maps coincide? I'm curious if the diagram implies that $d(\iota_U)_q$ and $d \iota_q$ are equal, or they are equal in some isomorphic sense.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician The vertical maps coincide if and only if the horizontal arrows are strict identities. In our case they are not, but it is common practice to "regard them as identities". This is a slight abuse ot notation. The alternative would be to insert pedantically the obvious isomorphisms whenever $d_p\iota$ occurs.